# Convert date to UTC using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Probably and easy answer to this but I can't seem to find a way to get moment.js to return a UTC date time in milliseconds. Here is what I am doing:

```
var date = $("#txt-date").val(),
    expires = moment.utc(date);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 138):

This is found [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs).  With a library like moment, I urge you to read the entirety of the documentation.  It's *really* important.

Assuming the input text is entered in terms of the users's local time:

```
 var expires = moment(date).valueOf();
```

If the user is instructed actually enter a UTC date/time, then:

```
 var expires = moment.utc(date).valueOf();
```

Comment: Edited - removed "easily".  :)

Comment: And if I already have a moment date-time with a timezone, how can I convert it to UTC?

Comment: @Alexander - `.utc()`

Comment: That doesn't work. That only changes the methods used on the date, not the date itself.

Comment: @Colleen - yes, but one would usually then call one of those methods, such as `.format()`, which would emit the UTC value.   It *can't* change the internal date value itself, because a `Date` is already tracking a UTC timestamp.  It's always just the methods called on it that determines whether to emit UTC or local time.  Moment is the same in that regard.

Comment: use `moment.utc(anotherMomentDate)`

Comment: Why is it so important to read in its entirety?

Answer (score 84):

I use this method and it works. ValueOf does not work for me.

```
moment.utc(yourDate).format()
```

Comment: This works as per documentation. converts local time to UTC.

Comment: There's something fishy here. I'm using moment.js ver. 2.17.1 and if 'yourdate' is to '2017-10-14T21:00:00Z' (en-us) then the above snippet returns the exact same result '2017-10-14T21:00:00Z' which obviously it's not utc since I'm in gmt+3. The correct result would be '2017-10-15T00:00:00+03:00' and you get this via 'moment(yourDate).format()'.

Comment: "moment": "^2.29.1", -> this works for me ---> moment().utc().format()

Answer (score 27):

As of : `moment.js version 2.24.0`

let's say you have a local date input, **this is the proper way** to convert your **dateTime** or **Time** input to **UTC**  :

```
var utcStart = new moment("09:00", "HH:mm").utc();
```

or in case you specify a date

```
var utcStart = new moment("2019-06-24T09:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm").utc();
```

As you can see the result output will be returned in UTC :

```
//You can call the format() that will return your UTC date in a string 
 utcStart.format(); 
//Result : 2019-06-24T13:00:00
```

But if you do this as below, it **will not** convert to UTC  :

```
var myTime = new moment.utc("09:00", "HH:mm");
```

You're only setting your input to utc time, it's as if your mentioning that myTime is in UTC, ....the output will be 9:00

Comment: If input is in UTC, var s = new moment("2019-06-24T09:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm").utc(); is the correct way to read. Further calls s.format() will convert it to local time.

Answer (score 8):

This will be the answer:

```
moment.utc(moment(localdate)).format()
```

```
localdate = '2020-01-01 12:00:00'

moment(localdate)
//Moment<2020-01-01T12:00:00+08:00>

moment.utc(moment(localdate)).format()
//2020-01-01T04:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 4):

```
moment.utc(date).format(...);
```

is the way to go, since

```
moment().utc(date).format(...);
```

does behave weird...

Comment: Could you please elaborate the weird behavior of `moment().utc(date).format(...)`?

Comment: The behaviour is not weird, those are different methods. The first `moment.utc(date)` is for [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) the `date`. The second `moment().utc(date)` is for [manipulating](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) the current time (`moment()`) and the `date` parameter is useless since this `.utc()` in this case doesn't expect any params.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. Others might find it useful.

```js
let date = '2020-08-31T00:00:00Z'
moment.utc(moment(date).utc()).format() // returns 2020-08-30T22:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, just reinitialize with an inverse of your local offset.

```
var timestamp = new Date();
var inverseOffset = moment(timestamp).utcOffset() * -1;
timestamp = moment().utcOffset( inverseOffset  );

timestamp.toISOString(); // This should give you the accurate UTC equivalent.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. What does work is setting the `keepOffset` parameter to true, as in `moment(timestamp).toISOString(true)`,

Answer (score 2):

This `moment.utc(stringDate, format).toDate()` worked for me.

This <strike>`moment.utc(date).toDate()`</strike> not.

Answer (score 2):

This works in my case.

Library: "moment": "^2.29.1",

```
moment().utc().format()
```

Answer (score 1):

here, I'm passing the date object and converting it into UTC time.

```
$.fn.convertTimeToUTC = function (convertTime) {
   if($(this).isObject(convertTime)) {
        return moment.tz(convertTime.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), moment.tz.guess()).utc().format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    }
};
// Returns if a value is an object
$.fn.isObject =  function(value) {
    return value && typeof value === 'object';
};


//you can call it as below
$(this).convertTimeToUTC(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this documentation of moment.js [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/). 
See below example and output where I convert GMT time to local time (my zone is IST) and then I convert local time to GMT.

```
// convert GMT to local time
console.log('Server time:' + data[i].locationServerTime)
let serv_utc = moment.utc(data[i].locationServerTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").toDate();
console.log('serv_utc:' + serv_utc)
data[i].locationServerTime = moment(serv_utc,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").tz(self.zone_name).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log('Converted to local time:' + data[i].locationServerTime)

// convert local time to GMT
console.log('local time:' + data[i].locationServerTime)
let serv_utc = moment(data[i].locationServerTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").toDate();
console.log('serv_utc:' + serv_utc)
data[i].locationServerTime = moment.utc(serv_utc,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log('Converted to server time:' + data[i].locationServerTime)
```

Output is

```
Server time:2019-12-19 09:28:13
serv_utc:Thu Dec 19 2019 14:58:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Converted to local time:2019-12-19 14:58:13
local time:2019-12-19 14:58:13
serv_utc:Thu Dec 19 2019 14:58:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Converted to server time:2019-12-19 09:28:13
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const localtime = 1622516400000
moment(localtime).utc(true).format()
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the author is asking

This will take out the time zone information and actually modify the localtime............

Answer (score 1):

We can get 2 UTC date formats.

```
const date = '2021-07-20T18:30:00Z';
moment.utc(moment(date).utc()).format(); // 2021-07-19T18:30:00Z
moment.utc(moment(date).utc()).toISOString(); // 2021-07-20T18:30:00.000Z (Complete ISO-8601)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
moment(date, format).utc().format(desireFormat)
```

for Example

```
moment('20-05-2020 10:12:44 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A')
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't you need something to compare and then retrieve the milliseconds?

For instance:

```
let enteredDate = $("#txt-date").val(); // get the date entered in the input
let expires = moment.utc(enteredDate); // convert it into UTC
```

With that you have the expiring date in UTC.
Now you can get the "right-now" date in UTC and compare:

```
var rightNowUTC = moment.utc(); // get this moment in UTC based on browser
let duration = moment.duration(rightNowUTC.diff(expires)); // get the diff
let remainingTimeInMls = duration.asMilliseconds();
```