# Date string to Date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Problem Question: I have a date string(could be in any format `31/10/93` or `10/31/93` or `93/10/31`) and want to convert this to date object(UTC format).

how to do this using momentjs ?

what I tried `moment.utc(date)` but no result.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse string with multiple formats as described [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/).

If you need you can also pass locale parameter.

The following code shows a possible solution to your question:

```js
var arr = ['31/10/93','10/31/93','93/10/31'];

for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
  var m = moment.utc(arr[i], ['DD/MM/YY', 'MM/DD/YY', 'YY/MM/DD']);
  console.log(m.format('DD MMMM YYYY')); // 31 October 1993
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine for the input you gave as example, but may give you unexepcted results for inputs like `01/02/93`. This string can represent both `1 February 1993` and `2 January 1993`.

The suggested code will show `01 February 1993` because, as stated in the docs:

> Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in valid dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later

---

If you need a JavaScript Date from moment object you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/) method, while if you need Unix timestamp you can use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) or [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/).

---

After your comment, I can suggest to get *"localized"* format using [`moment.localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/). Using `longDateFormat('L')` you can get localized format string and then use it in the parsing function. For example, `longDateFormat('L')` will return `MM/DD/YYYY` for `us` locale and `DD/MM/YYYY` for `it`. Code sample:

```js
var s = '01/02/93';

function formatSample(s){
  var ldf = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
  return moment.utc(s, [ldf, 'YY/MM/DD']).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
}

moment.locale('us');
formatSample(s); // 02 January 1993
moment.locale('it');
formatSample(s); // 01 febbraio 1993
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer is close enough! But i wish moment has something where it just look at the `moment.local()` and identify what format to use for the date to convert to UTC.

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets I've updated my answer trying to give you what you explained in your comment.

Comment: how do you change `2 February 2016` to user date format using local? like `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` or `YYYY/MM/DD`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the format, than you can't.
you must provide a format for the moment constructor because
1/2/93 can be first of feb or second of jan.
there is no way for moment.js to decide this for you correctly.

See following section for more info

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: can moment take format dynamically ? by passing the local ?

Comment: you give it the format each time you want it to parse the string and convert to moment object as follows: moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");