# Convert local time in an object to UTC using moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc

Consider the following object.

```
time: {
  hour: 3, 
  minute: "03", 
  hourType: "AM"
}
```

Is there a to convert the above time to UTC considering date is current date using moment.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to UTC using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) with [object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) parameter.

Since there is no key for AM/PM so you have to manage by yourself.

Here a live sample:

```js
var time = {
  hour: 3, 
  minute: "03", 
  hourType: "AM"
}
var m = moment.utc({
  hour: time.hourType=='AM' ? time.hour : 12 + time.hour,
  minutes: time.minute
});
console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```