# Convert date into specified time zone using moment

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have npm moment in my application using that need to convert selected time into the specified GMT timezone getting from server

my time zone is +5.30, I need to convert my local time into GMT and pass to the server

I tried the following code but its not converting to the GMT/ UTC time

`moment(new Date()).subtract(5.30, 'hour')).toDate() // getting wrong answer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to UTC using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js)