# How do I get a Date object on MomentJS but as UTC (prevent `toDate()` from being `locale`)?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, react-datepicker

First of all, I really need a `Date object` because I'm using `ReactDatePicker` and the `selected` prop requires it. And I also really have to use `momentjs`.

The bit of code I need to work with is this:

```js
// this logs a Moment object
const date = moment(moment.utc().format())

// this logs something like
// Tue Jul 20 2021 17:08:28 GMT+0100 (Western European Summer Time)
const dateObj = date.toDate()
```

As you can see, no matter the amount of times that I convert my `moment()` into `UTC`, `toDate()` always converts it back to `locale time` and I need to prevent this while still keeping a `Date object` that comes from `.toDate()`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.valueOf()` method.

Following on from your example

```js
// this logs a Moment object
const date = moment(moment.utc().valueOf())

// This will output something like 2021-07-20T16:14:39.636Z
const dateObj = date.toDate()
```

```js
// this logs a Moment object
const date = moment(moment.utc().valueOf())

// This will output something like 2021-07-20T16:14:39.636Z
const dateObj = date.toDate()

console.log("UTC time: ", dateObj)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but this doesn't seem to work.

Doing your answer I don't get `UTC` and instead I still get `locale time` from the `toDate()`.

Even the `moment(moment.utc().valueOf())` already delivers as `locale time`

Comment: The time is definitely UTC, depending on where you live UTC time (Coordinated Universal Time) might be the same as your local time. @ItzaMi

Comment: An [interesting website](https://time.is/time_zones) that groups countries together based on UTC offset.

Comment: this is weird.
I'm on GMT+1 and if log `moment(moment.utc().valueOf())` I get my current `locale` time and, of course, logging `moment(moment.utc().valueOf()).toDate()` is also logging me my `locale time`.

I can see that your example is working but I don't understand why it's doing this for me.
I'm using `"moment": "2.29.1"` on this React project

Comment: What does the output of `moment(moment.utc().valueOf()).toDate()` look like for you. You're on the latest version of moment.js.

Comment: Logging `moment(moment.utc().valueOf()).toDate()` gets me `Wed Jul 21 2021 10:42:13 GMT+0100 (Western European Summer Time)`

Comment: It seems like a bug with the `.toDate()` function, we both have the same syntax, same version and are getting different results. It might be worth deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

Comment: I guess that I'm indeed stuck here  Just updated my dependencies and still getting the same result. I noticed that you're using `2.27` on yours. Maybe something changed?

Comment: I've gone and tested this out in node using "moment":  "^2.29.1" and I'm still getting the same result as the snippet. It might be worth [creating an issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues) on [moment's GitHub page](https://github.com/moment/moment).

Comment: Yup, already doing that.
Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js#23305531).

Where someone found success by placing `.format()` out of the brackets. For me it yields the same result, but it might be worth trying if you are still having problems.

```js
const date = moment(moment.utc())

const dateObj = moment(date.format()) // Equivalent to moment(moment(moment.utc()).format())

console.log("UTC time: ", dateObj) // Should output UTC time
console.log("dateObj is an " + typeof dateObj)
console.log("dateObj is " + (dateObj._isAMomentObject ? "a moment object" : "not a moment object"))
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not work.
My prop is expecting a `Date` but `format()` gets me a `string`

Comment: @ItzaMi My bad, I've fixed the snippet to return a moment object.