# How can I get a Date object in UTC with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

So, I'm currently working on a date picker and I'm having some issues with being able to get a `Date object` that is in `UTC`.

Using a native way of getting it, like: `new Date(Date.UTC(96, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`, my `log` shows `Fri Feb 02 1996 04:04:05 GMT+0100 (Western European Standard Time)`, which is obviously not `UTC`. But I'm asking for `UTC` on my method.

So what's happening here? How can I get a `Date` object (that I need to use on my `ReactDatePicker`) but in UTC?

Is there a way of doing this? Or is it just completely impossible?

Comment: All Date instances are UTC internally. The trick lies in what you do to turn the date back into a string. By default, it'll be a local time, but you can use the various [UTC methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods) to get information in UTC terms.

Comment: So if I need to feed a `Date object` into my component, I have no way of controlling this?

Comment: Yep, me again I left a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68471265/14861737) on your last post, did that end up working for you?

Comment: Your component can render the Date however it wants. The point is that there's no such thing as a "UTC Date", or else *all* Date instances are "UTC Dates".

Comment: Thank you, @Pointy, for the explanation. My `prop` always expects a `Date` and wanted to know if this `Date` can be `UTC` by default. Since that's not the case, I'm at a deadend. Thanks anyway

Comment: @lejlun, although `format()` could work, it gets me a `string` and I still need a `Date` so it's a no go as well

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` in JavaScript represents a particular moment in time. That moment in time has many different possible expressions in different possible timezones on Earth. You can serialize the moment a `Date` represents many different ways, but a `Date` does not have awareness of any particular local timezone.

It's a bit like asking "how do I get my number in binary/octal/hexidecimal?" Numbers represent magnitude along the number line, but can be expressed in different bases. A number-as-magnitude is agnostic to expression in any particular base, and can be serialized in any base. So too to `Date`s have temporal magnitude and any number of possible serializations.

By default, a `Date` will serialize to your local timezone, but you can also force it to serialize to it's expression in UTC using [`.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

If you really need a Date and a timezone together, you will need to create your own structure, e.g.,

```
{
    date: new Date(...),
    offset: -4
}
```

and write your own logic to serialize it when necessary.