# React Table shows entries based on User Time zone not UTC

Tags: utc

I have a table (react/Nodejs) which reads the entries from db and list it in the table. All entries in db are UTC, however depending on the user time zone the table is showing different data. For example in the attached snapshot our week on header is from Sep 19 to Sep 25 but the table shows Sep 26 entry which is outside of the range. That only happens with users on (UTC-xxx) time and not for user on (UTC+xxx). Your help is appreciated? [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geCj5.png)

Comment: This will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a timezone library to render it with a specific timezone

The problem is caused when formatting the object to be rendered in the UI, so probably the method you are using is as you say taking into account the users timezone and not a specific one that you set.

To achieve this, you can use a library like [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/). Or a variant compatible with your libraries.

Hope it helps.